# Why is my plotly library not plotting graphs

Tags: python

I've been using plotly library in python lately (it is my first time using it) to plot a candlestick chart of bitcoin, but for some reason it is not plotting the graph and showing "The site can't be reached". Here's the code and it's output!

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv('Bitstamp_AAVEBTC_d.csv')
df = df.iloc[::-1]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Candlestick(x = df['date'],
                        open = df['open'], high = df['high'],
                        low = df['low'], close = df['close'])])
# print(df)
fig.show()
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: could you share the sample of data from Bitstamp_AAVEBTC_d.csv?

Comment: please post the complete traceback of the error. are you sure the error is for the code you posted? because there is no site to be reached in your code.

Comment: there is no error in the code, but the graph is not showing up

Answer (score 0):

This error message typically arises when attempting to display a Plotly figure in an environment such as a Jupyter Notebook which relies on a web-based interface. You can use `plotly.offline` to render the plotly figure directly within your Jupyter Notebook or a local environment in order to avoid the attempt to open it in a web browser. Here's how to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)  

df = pd.read the CSV file('Bitstamp_AAVEBTC_d.csv')
df = df.iloc[::-1]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['date'], open=df['open'], high=df['high'], low=df['low'], close=df['close'])])

iplot(fig)
```

Comment: still not displaying the graph but showing a lot of numbers in the terminal

Comment: If you're encountering an excessive display of numerical data in your terminal while using the `iplot` method, it could suggest a configuration problem in your Jupyter Notebook or a compatibility issue. To tackle this, you can explore an alternative method using the `plotly.express` library, which streamlines the process of creating candlestick charts.